# Overfitted Cox regression

Tags: predictive-models, cox-model

I'm trying to compare the prediction abilities for death of two new biomarkers using a cohort of 173 patients. My problem is that I have only 31 outcomes and my baseline model (the one without any biomarker) contains 7 variables.

Using SPSS I can bootstrap (and I did that) to overcome the problem of overfitting and to determine the adequate (I don't know if this is the correct word for it) 95% CI for B.

But latter in the analysis I want to compare the subsequent two models (the ones with the new biomarkers) with the baseline model (INI, NRI, C statistic).
How can I overcome the fact that my models are overfitted and still perform these analyses? Can I use the models "as they are" or should I perform additional statistical procedures on them before further analysis?

Thank you.

Comment: The first part of Q.1 is about correct or advisable procedure statistically and seems throughly on-topic. The remainder of Q.1 and Q.2 are how to do stuff in R and are off-topic here. Please read advice in the Help Center on software-related questions.

Comment: Thank you for this ascertainment. In conclusion, it is advisable to first bootstrap and then use the survIDINRI package?

Comment: I am just traffic cop here. Despite the coincidence of my surname, I don't use these methods ever. (Again, advice on what software to use is off-topic here.)

Comment: My problem is, basically, how can I overcome the fact that these Cox models are overfitted - what methods should I apply to latter be able to perform additional analyses? Thank you.

Comment: Best advice is to rewrite the question!